# Ingres error trying to query timestamp without timezone column

Tags: sql, ingres

I'm trying to write a query on a column that's of the time "Timestamp without timezone" and this is my where clause:

```
and (cv.expire_ts >= 'today' or ifnull(cv.expir_ts, '') = '')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: 'today' is invalid format or value for timestamp without time zone or timestamp with local time zone. Please enter a valid timestamp value in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff...] format.
SQLState:  22007
ErrorCode: 4328
Error: Specified cursor is not known to the server.
SQLState:  24000
ErrorCode: 590366
```

How can I make this query work on this type of column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `CURRENT_DATE` constant, without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think missing part is date function for `'today'`

[Refer](http://www.actian.com/kb/article/332083)

Comment: I was trying to say you to use `date` function for getting value of system's today like `select date('today');`